# how http gzip plus caching for subsequent requests works?

Tags: javascript, http, caching, gzip

I have applied gzip compressions in my http responses for JS files with caching applied. For first time, gzipped JS is being sent with 200OK response. Then for all subsequent requests for these JS files are being served from browser cache. I want to know whether browser pick JS file every time  in compressed format for parsing or after first request, uncompressed JS file is saved to disk cache and for all subsequent requests browser parser gets uncompressed file.

Comment: My guess would be that it stores the uncompressed file, as gzip is used as _transfer_ encoding. But it's ultimately up to the browser how it exactly implements its cache (perhaps it compresses all compressable data to keep the cache size smaller, for instance). Why do you want to know?

Comment: i wanted to check because if browser is saving compressed and every time uncompress it while picking it up for parsing/interpretation , it will be overhead i guess.

Comment: I think the overhead will be negligable, though.